# Is the hyperspace tracking technology in The Last Jedi the same as the one seen in Star Wars Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, star-wars-rebels

In The Last Jedi we have the First Order tracking the Resistance through hyperspace, and this is treated as brand new cutting edge technology previously thought to be impossible.

But in the Star Wars Rebels episode "Gathering Forces" (S1 E09), we also have the Empire tracking the crew of the Ghost through hyperspace, via a tracking device that they attached to the ship. The crew of the Ghost does not seem particularly stunned that this tracking technology exists. This is decades before the events of TLJ.

Is this the same technology? If so, why are Finn and Rose so shocked by it in TLJ? is there an in-universe explanation?

Comment: The difference is that there was a tracking device hidden on the Ghost, and there was no tracking device hidden on any of the resistance vessels in TLJ.  (Now, how the resistance *knew* there wasn't a tracking device remains unexplained ...)

Comment: I'm not sure this should actually be considered a duplicate... the other question listed as being exactly the same is about HOW the First Order was tracking the Resistance ships, but this is asking about differences between two devices/types of tech that do the same thing, as well as about the continuity of it. The questions are similar, but they're actually asking about two different things...